# Hibernate type. ListArrayType for list of java objects

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I had entity with a field book inside like jsob type in db.
Postgres, hibernate 6+

```
@Entity
public class Author {
  ....

  @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
  @Column(name = "book")
  private Book book;
}

  Sql script : 
  CREATE TABLE author 
  ....
  book        JSONB,
  ....
```

```
public class Book {
  private UUID id;
  private String name;

  ....
}
```

But now I need to replace book with list of books. Tried something like this:

```
  ... 

  @Type(
      value = ListArrayType.class,
      parameters = {@Parameter(name = ListArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "book")})
  @Column(name = "books", columnDefinition = "book[]")
  private List<Book> books; 


CREATE TYPE book AS (id UUID, name VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE author 
  ....
  book        book[],
  ....
```

But exception occurs:

> Unable to find server array type for provided name book

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Comment: What is `ListArrayType`? There's no such class in Hibernate.

Comment: @GavinKing io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array

Comment: So it would have been better to mention in the problem description that you're using a third-party lib that is not part of Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate 6 features built-in support for this, and the code should be as simple as:

```java
private List<Book> books;
```

to map to a SQL array type, or:

```java
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
private List<Book> books;
```

to map to a JSON type.

Comment: when I use @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) ide underline field in red with message: 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

Comment: That is a message from your IDE plugin, not from Hibernate. Did you try actually *running* it?

Comment: Hibernate documentation itself recommends: "Hibernate even allows mapping a collection as @Basic, but that should generally be avoided." - so a solution would be to configure this in IDE options accordingly as warning or just add '@ElementCollection'.